# How to understand the event listeners execution on window object?

Tags: javascript

I am using `window.addEventListener('message', fun)` to register a few event listeners. What will happen if there is one event listener throws an exception? Whether other event listeners run as usual or are impacted by this exception? Is there a way to catch all exceptions outside `fun` function?

Comment: `fun` should be solely responsible to handle that exception. Ideally, there should not be any other impact of `fun` throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `fun` event listener, if you think an exception may be thrown, you should catch it and handle it inside the function.

```
function fun(){
 try{
   //something that may throw an exception
 }catch(err){
   console.log(err.message);//log the exception message
   //handle exception
 }
}
```

If you want to catch all unhandled thrown exceptions, you can use `window.onerror()`.

```js
window.onerror = function(e){
 alert(e);
}
undefinedFunction();
```